# How can I model OTHER_FILES from qmake with CMake?

Tags: qt, cmake, qt-creator, qmake

In `qmake` based projects, it's possible to include `OTHER_FILES` to use them in QtCreator, e.g.

```
QT += core gui widgets
TARGET = example-program
TEMPLATE = app

HEADERS = mainwindow.h
SOURCES = main.cpp mainwindow.cpp

OTHER_FILES = README.md LICENCE examples/network/server.c
```

That way one can access `README.md` within QtCreator easily. A CMake file with the  same target looks like

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(example CXX)

set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)

find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS Core Gui Widgets REQUIRED)

set(HEADERS mainwindow.h)
set(SOURCES main.cpp mainwindow.cpp)
set(OTHER_FILES README.md LICENCE examples/network/server.c)

add_executable(example-program ${SOURCES} ${HEADERS})
target_link_libraries(example-program Qt5::Core Qt5::Gui Qt5::Widgets)
```

However, the `OTHER_FILES` aren't shown in QtCreator and I have to access them via "File > Open" instead of the project browser. Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [a custom target](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_target.html?highlight=add_custom_target) that depends on the given files:

```
add_custom_target(project-related-files SOURCES ${OTHER_FILES})
```

Since the `COMMAND` is missing, an empty target will be generated, but it will still depend on the `SOURCES`. This is also the official way to include other files into an IDE:

> `SOURCES`
>       Specify additional source files to be included in the custom target. Specified source files will be added to IDE project files for convenience in editing even if they have no build rules.

Answer (score 5):

There's no problem with adding non-compiled files as the sources of a CMake target; CMake will simply ignore them if it doesn't recognise their extension. So you can easily do this:

```
add_executable(example-program ${SOURCES} ${HEADERS} ${OTHER_FILES})
```

With files which could be confused for actual sources (based on their extension), there's always the option of setting their `HEADER_FILE_ONLY` property to true:

```
set_source_files_properties(
  ${OTHER_FILES}
  PROPERTIES
  HEADER_FILE_ONLY TRUE
)
```

Comment: Ah, but sometimes you have examples in `.<language-extension>` files, e.g. `examples/network/server.c`. Will that still work? `OTHER_FILES` in qmake get completely ignored in the Makefile generation.

Comment: @Zeta No, those would get picked up by default, but you can make them exempt; answer updated.

Comment: That leads to recompilation of `example-program` if any file in `OTHER_FILE` has been changed, though, doesn't it?

Comment: @Zeta No, it most definitely should not.

Comment: At the moment (18 Mar 2022), this answer has a higher score than the accepted answer. Why is that? The accepted answer is more concise and appears to meet the OP's needs.

Answer (score 0):

I'll comment that I think both answers are correct, which to use depends on the particulars of the project.

[Angew's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50135348/169296) adds the files to a single project, within the project.

In my case, [Zeta's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50135281/169296) worked better, as I had files at the top-level of a project with subprojects, and having a new folder (with a name I could customize) in QtCreator better fit my needs.

Adding an additional answer, as I didn't see the differences between the two approaches mentioned.